# Customization of UITableViewSection Header

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can i have a Section header Customise as follows :

[image]

I know we can use

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but is this kind of customisation possible ??I have the respective images.

My Current Section Header

[image]

Please let me know as this is kind of very important.

Thank You.

Best Regards.

***UPDATE***

Hey i am glad i almost did this what i want to know is, Now how can i get the date on image view, that is the image is overlapping the date on section header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:68/255.0 alpha:1]];

    UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 61)];
    [img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_bg.png"]];

    UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(66, 0, 173, 61)];
    [img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_bg.png"]];

    UIImageView *img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(239, 0, 65, 61)];
    [img3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange_bg.png"]];

    [headerView addSubview:img1];
    [headerView addSubview:img2];
    [headerView addSubview:img3];


    return headerView;
}
```

This is my sectionHeader and the view after i add the images.

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible. Why wouldn't it be? You can have any view with whatever subviews you want as a section header.

Comment: @rdelmar : Hey !! yes i did achieve what i wanted.But now the issue is the Images are overlapping the date on section.If you have a look at my previous section it has date fetched from parser, but when i add images they overlap the date.

Comment: @rdelmar : what do i do to bring the date on respective images.

Comment: What images are overlapping what date? I don't see anything overlapping in the image you posted.

Comment: @rdelmar : when i add images in viewForHeaderInSection they seem to overlap the date. (Please see the second image in my question for reference).Those date's are fetched by parser.

Comment: Your image views need to have UILabels as subviews, to which you add the correct date components.

Comment: @rdelmar : Thank You. Probably Hercules has specified it in answer.But the text on label is not static it is coming from web service . If you could check my Original section image. (Gray one)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34422/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-icode-atapple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the image you have uploaded and use that...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eu96Z.png"];

    UILabel *lbl1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 61)];
    lbl1.text=@"17";
    lbl1.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [img addSubview:lbl1];

    return img;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44;
}
```

Use following blank image and add label as subView to it.

[image]

Check edited answer

If u get date together then separate it using

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *str = @"07/13/2013";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *date = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *month = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
month = [[[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:([month intValue]-1)] uppercaseString];
NSString *year = [arr objectAtIndex:2];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",date,month,year);
```

And set it where ever you want to set.